How electric potential can have a maxima?, does it violates Laplace equation?
For a static charge distribution,$\nabla^2V=-\rho/\varepsilon_0$ holds true. and for regions with $\rho=0$, $\nabla^2V=0$ holds true. This is Laplace’s Equation. Now solutions of Laplace’s equation allows no maxima or minima, unless it is on the boundary.

Now, consider the static charge distribution at centre of this cube. This is a local maxima of electric potential. Isn’t this not supposed to be allowed?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As pointed out in this answer by Qmechanic, the Laplace equation does allow for saddle points in the interior boundary. So you can definitely have $\mathbf{E} = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}V = 0$ in the center of the cube without contradicting the Laplace equation's maximum principle.
